# Ubuntu 14.04 ATI/Intel Hybrid Graphics DPM

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 with hybrid ATI/Intel graphics. (AMD Radeon 7670M / Intel HD 4000) using Ubuntu 14.04 with open source drivers for graphics. (xserver-xorg-video-ati)

I read that Ubuntu 14.04 with the linux kernel version 3.13 supports auto switching between graphics and dynamic power management. Is it correct?

Anyway, if it is true, I dont think that it is working in my system , because fan runs constantly and battery backup is less than 2 hours.

```
lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
```

What should I do?
Is there any hope that this gets fixed in future kernels?

Answer (score 1):

try installing the `fglrx` driver, as documented in the official ubuntu wiki
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```